# Python Teradata auto increment starts with a 6 digit number instead of 1?

Tags: python, mysql, teradata

I want to create a table in Teradata that uses auto-increment in the ID column. The code works, but i just dont know why the ID starts like 100001, 100002.. ect despite stating a `start with 1 increment by 1`.

This is my code:

```
cur = connection.cursor()
```

## create table

```
create_stmt = """CREATE TABLE my_table,
                                NO FALLBACK,
                                NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
                                NO AFTER JOURNAL,
                                CHECKSUM = DEFAULT
                                ( 
                                 id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 NO CYCLE),
                                word VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET UNICODE, 
                                country VARCHAR(50) 
                                ) 
                                PRIMARY INDEX (id);"""
cur.execute(create_stmt)
```

## insert into table

```
insert_stmt = """INSERT INTO my_table (word,country) VALUES(?,?);"""
mydata=("hello","USA")
my_query=cur.execute(insert_stmt,my_data)
```

## select all to test

```
sel_all_stmt="sel * from my_table"
cur.execute(sel_all_stmt)
result = cur.fetchall()
```

I ran the insert statement a few times to see what the auto increment look like and this is what i got:

```
[(100001, u'hello', u'USA'), (1, u'hello', u'USA'), (200001, u'hello', u'USA'), (400001, u'hello', u'USA'), (300001, u'hello', u'USA')]
```

Any idea why the id is so long?

Answer (score 1):

Sequential processing defeats the purpose of a massive parallel DBMS.

Teradata's `IDENTITY` is not a single sequence, it's multiple sequences in parallel (btw, Standard SQL compliant): Each Parsing Engine (PE) and each AMP requests a range of values and assignes them sequentially. So the numbers assigned to rows within a PE/AMP *are* sequential, but not across PEs/AMPs.

[More details can be found in the manuals.](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/SQL_Reference/B035_1184_151K/Create_Table-Details.013.033.html#ww2393097)